# Calculate the voltage across a load resistor for complex transmission lines

Tags: transmission-line, impedance-matching, reflection

The following parameters are given:

500m homogeneous transmission line.

```
R' = 4.6 Ohm/km
G' = 0.5 uS/km
L' = 2 mH/km
C' = 800nF/km
r2 = 0.6 (sendondary side refl. coeff.)
ω = 200k
Uin = U1 = 60V + 0j
```

Question: What is the voltage U2 across the Load impedance ZL? For ω= 200k and Uin = 60V

My Idea:

Calculating ZW first (Wire Impedance)
[image]

Then calculating the Load Impedance: 
[image]

Now i think about this circuit like two series impedances and i think i could use the resistor dividor approach to get the voltage u2 across the Load impedance:

[image]

Calculating:
[image]

Unfortunately this result isnt correct. 
I am not be able to figure out where i did a mistake.

Do i have to take the refl. coeff into account again?

Would be happy about anything helpful. 
Thanks.

Comment: ω=0 ? at Uin ..

Comment: ω is 200k at Uin = 60V

Comment: What is the supposed correct result?

Comment: The correct result is probably: 88.174V * e^(j163 Deg)

Comment: Why do you call r2 the "secondary side" reflection coefficient?  Is there a transformer in your system? Is your transmission line connected to the secondary side or the primary side of the transformer?

Comment: the "transformer" is the transmission line. r1 would be the coefficient between the source (generator) and the transmission line r2 is the coefficient after the transmission line. Between the output and the load.

Comment: The source is 0 Ohms? or 50 Ohms and rated at 60V with a 50 Ohm load and thus 88V with a 200 Ohm load??

Comment: The Source is matched to the transmission line. Therefore at the input of the transmission line, we can measure or we would measure 60V.

Comment: You're still missing one critical parameter: The length of the transmission line.

Answer (score 1):

you calculated the impedance of the transmission line, but you failed to take into account that is per unit of distance, km in this case you just need to divide each parameter you got by half(500m is 0.5km) and it should be fine.

I see no other errors in your calculation.